# what is the best place to learn shopify theme developing?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Is it possible for anyone to nominate a place, documentation or tutorial to learn developing Shopify themes?
I have learned liquid Shopify template language but I can not understand how should I use it in my template or my client's template that I made with (html5 / bootstrap / css3 / js / OOp js / jquery)
Any answer will certainly be useful
thanks.

Comment: Requests for tutorials or similar are off topic on stack overflow [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you have specific questions about a coding problem after working your way through a tutorial, come back here to ask those specific, answerable programming questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for shopify theme development ,you can learn here https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/topics/shopify-theme-development